# Making smaller version of canvas an objects in p5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

So I am trying to make a exact smaller scale version of my canvas and sprites in p5.js and fit it in a box. Is there a function or way I can do this? The background, colors, and images of the sprites should be the same.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to do this, one way is to draw everything to a `p5.Graphics` buffer and the draw that buffer to your main canvas twice with different destination sizes. The other way is to do the main part of your drawing directly to your canvas, and then use the `pixels` array to create a `p5.Image` from the content of your canvas and then draw that to the canvas with the `image` function.

### Example 1. `p5.Graphics`

```js
let graphics;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth * 0.9, windowHeight * 0.9);
  graphics = createGraphics(width, height);

  graphics.background(100);
}

function draw() {
  graphics.ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 50, 50);

  image(graphics, 0, 0, width, height, 0, 0, graphics.width, graphics.height);

  // Draw picture in picture
  let aspect = width / height;
  image(graphics, 10, 10, 100, 100 / aspect, 0, 0, graphics.width, graphics.height);
  push();
  noFill();
  strokeWeight(3);
  rect(10, 10, 100, 100 / aspect);
  pop();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.3.1/p5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

### Example 2. pixels & image

Note: this option has the disadvantage of being more complicated, waaay slower, and it doesn't support persistently drawn content as well as the `p5.Graphics` option because it displays itself on subsequent frames.

```js
let img;
let density;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(round(windowWidth * 0.9), round(windowHeight * 0.9));
  density = pixelDensity();

  img = createImage(width, height);
  img.loadPixels();

  background(100);
}

function draw() {
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 30, 30);

  loadPixels();
  for (let x = 0; x < width; x++) {
    for (let y = 0; y < height; y++) {
      let srcPixel = y * 4 * width * density ** 2 + x * 4 * density;
      let dstPixel = y * 4 * img.width + x * 4;
      for (let channel = 0; channel < 4; channel++) {
        img.pixels[dstPixel + channel] = pixels[srcPixel + channel];
      }
    }
  }
  img.updatePixels();

  // Draw picture in picture
  let aspect = width / height;
  image(img, 10, 10, 100, 100 / aspect, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
  push();
  noFill();
  strokeWeight(3);
  rect(10, 10, 100, 100 / aspect);
  pop();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.3.1/p5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Note: I was unaware of the `copy` function that @jstl pointed out. That looks like a great option.

Comment: This method works so thanks for that but I am getting major lag. I have player-controlled sprites so that might be the reason. Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: @AnikDey are you following example 1 or example 2? Example 1 should have better performance. If you have a running example you can share somewhere it would be easier to look into potential performance improvements.

Comment: I'm using example 2 because I have a controllable character so I have to update the pixels. Here is the github to my sketch.js file: https://github.com/AnikDey-exe/Sketch-Js-Minimap

Comment: So yeah, both using `copy`, and using `pixels` are unfortunately pretty slow. I even tried making it heavily downsampled and it was still slow. The bottom line is that the p5.play library is placing some unfortunate constraints on you because it seems to be tightly coupled to the global p5 context. Ideally you could find a way to get p5.play to draw to a p5.Graphics object and use Example #1.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how p5.play works, but I'm guessing that the `copy()` command ([reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/copy)) will do what you're looking for. To put the minimap in the bottom corner, you might do something like this:

```
function draw() {
  //whatever is currently in your draw loop...
  let minimapWidth = 50;
  let minimapHeight = 50;
  copy(0, 0, width, height, 
       width-minimapWidth, 
       height-minimapHeight, 
       minimapWidth, minimapHeight
      );
}
```